# Method overload as default

Tags: vb.net, overloading

I have a bit of an issue here: but the question is applicable for any method overloading.

I had a method declaration like: (witch did not match the requirements exactly)

```
Public Shared Sub SetGridFormat(ByRef grid As DataGrid, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer, ByVal paging As Boolean)
```

So I had in mind to write an overload for the cases I need this one:

```
   Public Shared Sub SetGridFormat(ByRef grid As DataGrid, ByVal width As Unit, ByVal height As Unit, ByVal paging As Boolean)
```

The two declarations are identical but the types of height and width. I got an "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'SetGridFormat' is most specific for these arguments" error.

The question is : does vb.net allow "default" definition method in case builder can not decide which one to use and what is the syntax?

Tanks for helping.

**EDIT : The 2 calls look like:**

```
SetGridFormat(dg, New Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage), New Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage), True)
SetGridFormat(dg, 100, 100,True)
```

From the responses, I just need to specify something: Most of the answers would work in most cases, but exclude the problematic case I have to deal with where the 2 values can be set to nothing (where no specific sizes are needed).

```
SetGridFormat(dg, Nothing, Nothing, True)
```

In this case, both method declaration are the same in the compiler point of view:

This is probably the root cause of the problem. I would be very disappointed if nothing exists for those cases. :(

My question was is there a way to force the compiler to use a specific method call in this case?

Comment: I don't think there is a "default" overload specifier.  What is `Unit` (a class, a enum, etc.)?

Comment: What is the type of the arguments you are passing into the method when you call it.  Apparently what you are passing it is neither Integers nor Units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a Default Specifier but you don't need to specify a default because the compiler will decide which one to call based on the argument types:

Consider the following:

```
Dim dg as DataGrid = Nothing
Dim widthInt as Integer = 0, HeightInt as Integer = 0
Dim pg as Boolean = False
Dim widthUnit as Unit = "Defaultvalue", heightUnit as Unit = "Defaultvalue"

SetGridFormat(dg, widthInt, heightInt, pg) ' Calls your first method
SetGridFormat(dg, widthUnit, heightUnit, pg) ' Calls your second method
```

If you really need to you could coerce the compiler into using a particular method by converting the type to the one required (this will obviously fail if the object cannot be converted to the type required however):

```
SetGridFormat(dg, CType(AnyObject,Integer), CType(AnyObject,Integer), pg) ' Calls your first method
SetGridFormat(dg, CType(AnyObject,Unit), CType(AnyObject,Unit), pg) ' Calls your first method
```

---

So in your case where you want to call a specific method with `Nothing` you *can* do this:

```
SetGridFormat(dg, CType(Nothing,Integer), CType(Nothing,Integer), pg) ' Calls your first method
SetGridFormat(dg, CType(Nothing,Unit), CType(Nothing,Unit), pg) ' Calls your first method
```

But this seems like bad design in the first place to me as calling one or the other with `Nothing` as arguments should have the same effect so it shouldn't matter which one is called in this instance so I suppose you should really define a new overload:

```
Public Shared Sub SetGridFormat(ByRef grid As DataGrid, ByVal paging As Boolean)
```

Comment: Yes, but OP is getting a "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'SetGridFormat' is most specific for these arguments" error from the compiler.

Comment: This works... But not clean at all... I think I will change the declaration a bit to avoid this problem: Public Shared Sub SetGridFormat(ByRef grid As DataGrid, ByVal width As integer, ByVal height As integer, ByVal unitType as UnitType, ByVal paging As Boolean).

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly no way to specify a default.  However, you can use the following syntax to perform a narrowing conversion (if I've read the question correctly):

```
Public Shared Sub SetGridFormat(ByRef grid As DataGrid, ByVal iWidth As Integer, ByVal iHeight As Integer, ByVal paging As Boolean)
Public Shared Sub SetGridFormat(ByRef grid As DataGrid, ByVal uWidth As Unit, ByVal uHeight As Unit, ByVal paging As Boolean)

SetGridFormat(dg, iWidth:=50, iHeight:=50, true)
SetGridFormat(dg, uWidth:=50, uHeight:=50, true)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, the method used will have to be defined by you and it will be the most specific (close by type) to the arguments used.
If you have
`yourMethod1(var1 as DataType1);

yourMethod1(var1 as DataType2);`

and

`DataType1 [extends DataType0];

DataType2 [extends DataType0];`

then you will HAVE to use DataType1 OR DataType2 (or some types extending them) arguments in your calls to yourMethod1(...), otherwise the calls will fail.

On the other hand if

`DataType1 [extends DataType0];

DataType2 extends DataType1;`

then your calls to to `yourMethod1(...)` with ANY argument of type extending DataType2 will execute `yourMethod1(var1 as DataType2)` the ONLY way of executing `yourMethod1(var1 as DataType1)` will be to call yourMethod1(...) with argument of type DataType1 (or extending DataType1 directly - NOT via DataType2).